# functional equation of entire functions shall have only constant solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an entire function $f$ with $f'(0)=0$ and a function $g$ holomorphic (at least) in $\mathbb D:=\{z\in\mathbb C\ |\ |z|<1\}$ such that $f*g$ is entire as well and satisfies the functional equation
$$
f(z)=(f*g)(z^2),\qquad z\in\mathbb C.
$$
I am looking for conditions on $g$ and/or the coefficients of the power series of $g$ which guarantee that $f$ must be a constant function.

**Example:** If $g(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$, then $f*g=f$, and the above equation reduces to
$$
f(z)=f(z^2),\qquad z\in\mathbb C.
$$
Here it is relatively easy to show that $f$ must be constant (Maximum Principle and Cauchy's Estimates will basically do).

I guess a similar argument would work if $g$ is a polynomial... but what about functions like $g(z)=e^z$?

**Remark:** The $*$ means the Hadamard product (convolution) of two holomorphic functions, that is, if $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ and $g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kz^k$, then
$$
(f*g)(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kb_kz^k.
$$

Thx in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the functional equation is $f(z) = (f\ast g)(z^2)$ and not $f(z^2) = (f\ast g)(z)$? As is, the functional equation implies that $f$ is constant and the only constraint on $g$ is that $b_0 = 1$ if $a_k \neq 0$.

Comment: You know, _some_ kind of reaction to the answer would be appreciated. "Thanks, but actually I'm looking for ...", or "Thanks, very helpful", or so. The complete silence is like you're not interested at all.

Comment: Sry for the silence. The thing is, your solution for the above problem is brilliant, but after thinking about my problem more intensively, I noticed that the functional equation I need to investigate is much more complicated than the above one. Moreover, using power series expensions and comparing coefficients does not work in the general setting (since you get really complicated recursive conditions for the coefficients), and I was wondering if there is a solution without that method. Once again: Sry! I am really thankful for your help!

Comment: Maybe your actual problem is not as hopeless as it looks. Can you shortly describe it? Or maybe post a new question, if the description doesn't fit in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the functional equation is indeed $f(z) = (f\ast g)(z^2)$, we have an equality of power series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n z^{2n}.\tag{1}$$

Since on the right hand side, only even powers of $z$ occur with a possibly nonzero coefficient, the same holds on the left, so $a_{2m+1} = 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. But that means that only the terms for even $n$ on the right may be nonzero, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}z^{2k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}b_{2n} z^{2(2n)}.\tag{2}$$

But now we see that on the right all powers of $z$ not divisible by $4$ have coefficient $0$, and hence the same applies on the left, $a_{4m+2} = 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{4k}z^{4k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{4n} b_{4n}z^{8n}.\tag{3}$$

Per induction, for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2^m\cdot k} z^{2^m\cdot k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2^m\cdot n} b_{2^m\cdot n} z^{2^{m+1}\cdot n},\tag{4}$$

from which we deduce that all coefficients $a_r$ for $r \equiv 2^{m} \pmod{2^{m+1}}$ must vanish.

Hence $a_k = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, and $(1)$ simplifies to

$$a_0 = a_0 b_0,$$

which is $a_0 = 0 \lor b_0 = 1$. So regardless of $g$, a functional equation $f(z) = (f\ast g)(z^2)$ implies that $f$ is constant (and if $g(0)\neq 1$, then $f\equiv 0$).

---

If, however, the intended functional equation was $f(z^2) = (f\ast g)(z)$, things become more interesting. Then we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{2k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n z^n,\tag{A}$$

and it follows that we have $a_{2m+1}b_{2m+1} = 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_{k} = a_{2k}b_{2k}$ for all $k$.

Again, we have $f(0) = 0$ or $g(0) = 1$. To deduce that $f$ must be constant, we look what conditions on the $b_n$ imply that $a_k = 0$ for all $k > 0$.

The relation $a_k = a_{2k}b_{2k}$ for all $k$ implies that if $b_{2^m\cdot k} = 0$ for some $m$, then we must also have $a_{2^j\cdot k} = 0$ for all $0 \leqslant j < m$.

So a simple sufficient condition is that $b_{2n} = 0$ for all $n > 0$.

On the other hand, $b_{2k} \neq 0$ implies $a_k = 0 \iff a_{2k} = 0$, so another simple sufficient condition is that $b_n \neq 0$ for all $n > 0$, since $b_{2m+1} \neq 0$ implies $a_{2m+1} = 0$, and then inductively $a_{2^j(2m+1)} = 0$ follows from $b_{2^j(2m+1)}\neq 0$ and $a_{2^{j-1}(2m+1)} = 0$.